# Проблема с JSON

Tags: json, javascript, ajax

$message - это ассоциативный массив возвращенный после запроса к БД

На сервере

```
     foreach($message as $mes)
  {
  $array = array('name' => $mes['name'], 'content' => $mes['content']);
  echo json_encode($array);
  }
```

На клиенте

```
     var message = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
```

Проблема в том, что мне надо передать все сообщения с БД, через JSON и вывести их через innerHTML, но оно передает только первое сообщения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так должно работать:

```
$res = array();
foreach( $message as $mes ){
  $res[] = array( 'name' => $mes['name'], 'content' => $mes['content'] );
}
echo json_encode( $res );
```

Comment: ток без $res = [];

Comment: Обновил ответ, исправив ошибки